# how to use initial_weights in h2o from R, when I use it I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: r, h2o

I want to do deeplearning using h2o with custom initial weights, if I do not add the initial_weights parameter the code runs fine, but if I add it, the error is keep showing.

```
wt1 = as.h2o(weight1)
   wt2 = as.h2o(weight2)
   wt3 = as.h2o(weight3)
   wt4 = as.h2o(weight4)

   #building the model
   ann_h2o_model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = features,
                                  y = target,
                                  training_frame = Train_set_b,
                                  standardize = T,
                                  activation = "Tanh",
                                  hidden = c(6,6,6),
                                  epochs = 2500,
                                  adaptive_rate = TRUE,
                                  initial_weights = c(wt1,wt2,wt3,wt4))
java.lang.NullPointerException error
```

Answer (score 0):

Using initial weights can be tricky because you need to make sure to get the dimension right.  Here is a code snippet on how to figure out the correct weight dimension and then use it in when calling the model:

```
df <- as.h2o(iris)
dl1 <- h2o.deeplearning(x=1:4,y=5,training_frame=df,hidden=c(10,10),export_weights_and_biases = TRUE, seed=1234, reproducible=TRUE)

## get weights and biases.  This will give you the correct dimension.
w1 <- h2o.weights(dl1,1)
w2 <- h2o.weights(dl1,2)
w3 <- h2o.weights(dl1,3)
b1 <- h2o.biases(dl1,1)
b2 <- h2o.biases(dl1,2)
b3 <- h2o.biases(dl1,3)

## make a model from given weights/biases
dl2 <- h2o.deeplearning(x=1:4,y=5,training_frame=df,hidden=c(10,10),initial_weights=c(w1,w2,w3),initial_biases=c(b1,b2,b3), epochs=0)
```